# Cloud Logging in GCP - basic example

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, cloud

I tried to log my message to google clog logs using the standard gcloud logs library code. It is throwoing an error message - "ImportError: cannot import name 'logging' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)". Please advise where I am doing wrong?

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
from google.cloud import logging

# Instantiates a client
logging_client = logging.Client()

# The name of the log to write to
log_name = "EN-LOG"
# Selects the log to write to
logger = logging_client.logger(log_name)

# The data to log
text = "My test message"

# Writes the log entry
logger.log_text(text)
```

I am expecting the log to be listed in the google clod logs explorer under the log name specified in the script "EN-LOG".
But it throwing an error when I try to run the script.
"ImportError: cannot import name 'logging' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)". Please advise where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try "import google.cloud.logging"

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#write_logs_with_the_standard_python_logging_handler

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).